# cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.HttpResponseException: Unauthorized

Tags: java, android, http, asynchronous

Hello  I'm trying to build a Clima app and I'm  Using `OpenWeatherMap` Api 
to retrieve weather data from the internet.
When I try the app on a physical device, I got this message **error:**

> `cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.HttpResponseException: Unauthorized`

I tried to generate a new API key but the same problem.

```
// TODO: Add letsDoSomeNetworking(RequestParams params) here:
protected void letsDoSomeNetworking(RequestParams params) {
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get(WEATHER_URL, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode ,Header[] header , JSONObject response){
            Log.d("Clima", "onSuccess: " + response.toString());
        }

        public void onFailure (int statusCode , Header[] headers , Throwable e , JSONObject response){
            Log.d("Clima", "Onfailure: " + statusCode);
            Log.d("Clima", "fail: " + e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(WeatherController.this, "requestFialed " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it s highly like you didn't change  this variable
final String APP_ID = "e****************************a"; on the weathercontroller.java
you're supposed to write yout own app_id , you can your own key by signing up at 
http://api.openweathermap.org/ , you will get the app_id on your email and the key will be activated within 1hour or 2 . best of luck buddy!